# Future Value prediction using SimpleRNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, prediction

I have a dataset with 3 columns, [A,B,C] and 11 rows. I would like to use simple RNN to predict the next value in the C column with data I have.
The values in column C are all dependent on A and B. They are all also increasing.
Example:

```
|   A | B  |  C  |
| --- | ---| --- |
|  1  | 2  |   3 |
|  3  | 4  |  7  |
|  5  | 6  |  11 |
|  …  |  … |  …  |
```

and so on.
*You can assume your own values for simplicity

And how would I graph the trained data against predicted data?

I imported the tensorflow modules, normalized and trained the data to predict. I got a value but it was less than the last value and the graph was didn’t really make sense.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN, Dense

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_data = data[:8]
test_data = data[8:]

# Normalize the data
mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data = (train_data - mean) / std
test_data = (test_data - mean) / std

# Define the input and output data
train_x = np.array(train_data[['A', 'B']])
train_y = np.array(train_data['C'])
test_x = np.array(test_data[['A', 'B']])
test_y = np.array(test_data['C'])

# Define the model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(32, input_shape=(2, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the model
history = model.fit(train_x.reshape(8, 2, 1), train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# Predict the next value in the C column
next_value = model.predict(test_x[-1].reshape(1, 2, 1))
next_value = next_value * std['C'] + mean['C']  # Invert the normalization
print("Next value in C:", next_value)

# Predict the values for the test set
test_pred = model.predict(test_x.reshape(3, 2, 1))
test_pred = test_pred * std['C'] + mean['C']  # Invert the normalization

# Plot the predicted values against the actual values
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(test_data['C'], label='Actual')
plt.plot(test_pred, label='Predicted')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

first of all, please use more data. Go to Kaggle and look for a timeseries dataset that makes sense. Neural nets will not work with a dataset that small.
As to the graph, when you print out the values you are plotting, you will see what's the problem:

```
test_data['C'] 8     1.837117
9     2.245366
10    2.653614
Name: C, dtype: float64
test_pred [[33.40863 ]
 [35.551506]
 [37.14804 ]]
```

the series of your test data still has the indices 8-10 which is why they appear in a weird place. You need to remove those, or add them to test_pred.